# Lenova Thinkcentre QEU-9637 USB port not working

Tags: windows-xp

I had to reload Windows XP on this machine and now it won't recognize a thumb drive or an external USB drive so I can load the drivers back on it.  Any ideas?  It appears that the USB drivers should be native to Windows.

Comment: That was the problem.  I was trying to use an ancient version of Windows XP that didn't support USB 2.0.  I had to burn a copy of SP 2 onto a CD and run that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install all of the updates, particularly up to SP3 in order to resolve some of the issues XP has with USB2.0 devices.